# Using a function for retrieving config info compared to direct array access

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I use a config object to store configuration information. So something like this example:

```
var value = myObject.Get('name');
```

The actual config is stored in an array - ie `config['name'] = value`

There are a lot of calls to the Get() function - over 25,000. How significant would the difference be if that array was accessed directly instead of via he Get() call?

Also - in an animation that 25,000 could be done 60 times per second (!)

Comment: See also: [JavaScript: “Function calls are expensive” vs. “Keep functions small”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168939)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct access should be faster, but you should do some tests, because the code performance is often influenced by the js engine.

For example, it's about 50% faster to access an object's key through the dot synthax (`obj.key`) than the asociative array like one (`obj["key"]`) in chrome, while in firefox it's the other way around.
I recommend you don't do micro-optimisations before you end your project and only after you do some testing/research.

Comment: Presumably though both of those methods would be faster than a function call?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not overoptimizing until you have means to test how much this actually  effects things. Depending on the situations, this whole call could just end up inlined anyway.